# Hook into adding / removing items from list in python

Tags: python, list

I'd like to create a drop-in replacement for python's `list`, that will allow me to know when an item is added or removed. A subclass of list, or something that implements the list interface will do equally well. I'd prefer a solution where I don't have to reimplement all of list's functionality though. Is there a easy + pythonic way to do it?

Pseudocode:

```
class MyList(list):
    # ...
    def on_add(self, items):
        print "Added:"
        for i in items:
            print i

    # and the same for on_remove

l = MyList()
l += [1,2,3]
# etc.
```

Comment: I think you need to override `append`, `extend` and (a bit trickier) `__setitem__`.

Comment: Instead of overriding `list` (which is the correct thing to do, but a bit tricky), you could write a small wrapper over a list implementing only the API that you need.

Answer (score 5):

To see what functions are defined in list, you can do

```
>>> dir(list)
```

Then you will see what you can override, try for instance this:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __iadd__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        print "Adding"
        return list.__iadd__(self, *arg, **kwargs)
```

You probably need to do a few more of them to get all of it.

Comment: `__iadd__` it was. I tried with `__setitem__` and was wondering why the control was not following through that.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for userlist](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-UserList.html) tells you to subclass `list` if you don't require your code to work with Python <2.2. You probably don't get around overriding at least the methods which allow to add/remove elements. Beware, this includes the slicing operators.